# Create user on Jenkins but he can only proceed with approval or abort during build

Tags: jenkins

How do I create a user on Jenkins but he can only proceed with approval or abort during build? Can you guys help me to find the right role for this case? Thanksss

I created an "approval" role and gave access to overall "read" and jobs to "build" and "cancel". For item roles, I give jobs for "build", "cancel", and "read". After I give this role, the user for approval still cannot proceed or abort